# Which is more idiomatic: dotimes vs loop repeat?

Tags: loops, common-lisp

Which of these code samples is more idiomatic Common Lisp?

```
(dotimes (_ 10) (write-line "Hello"))
```

Or

```
(loop repeat 10 do (write-line "Hello"))
```

Or alternatively is there no preferred way of looping iteratively in Common Lisp and we should just use which-ever we feel like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *ANSI Common Lisp*, Paul Graham argues against the use of `loop`, because the standard is poorly specified ("The only real definition of this macro is its implementation..."); there are [dissenting opinions](https://courses.cs.northwestern.edu/325/readings/graham/graham-notes.html), however.

`dotimes` in your example is arguably simpler, but it requires the throwaway variable `_`. For that reason I prefer the `loop` here -- but opinions on `loop` do vary quite a bit. To your last point, as Peter Seibel [writes](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-standard-control-constructs.html), "Some Lisp hackers love LOOP; others hate it. LOOP's fans like it because it provides a concise way to express certain commonly needed looping constructs. Its detractors dislike it because it's not Lispy enough."

Answer (score 4):

It does not matter much. Use either one.

You can also add your own control operators:

```
(defmacro repeat (n &body body)
  `(loop repeat ,n do (progn ,@body)))
```

Then use it:

```
CL-USER 52 > (repeat 10
               (write-line "hello")
               (write-line "world"))
hello
world
hello
world
...
world
hello
world
NIL
```